# Can argparse be used to initialize default values for strings

Tags: python, argparse, defaults

I'd like to initialize essential variables for my Python script (3.4), while providing the end user a chance to change those variable definitions via command line options.  Looks like argparse is the way to go.  I've looked [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) to get started, and this has worked for all my use cases except the one below:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--con',dest='targFileName',default='targets.con')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(targFileName)
```

Resulting in an error:

```
bash-4.1$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
print(targFileName)
NameError: name 'targFileName' is not defined.
```

Surely I'm misreading the doc.   What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `args = parser.parse_args()`, but that does not define all of the arguments in the global scope.  That just returns an instance of a class that has attributes for your arguments.  To get that argument, use `args.targFileName`.  You could also say `args = vars(parser.parse_args())` so that you could use `args['targFileName']`.